# ModuleNotFoundError after installing PyUpSet

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import, upsetplot

Reference: https://github.com/ImSoErgodic/py-upset
Hello! I have installed pyupset via both pip, pip3, and the source directly, as described in the link above. The terminal is saying that I have it completely downloaded. However, when I go to spyder and type "Import pyupset", I get the ModuleNotFoundError. After some research, it seems as though there's a discrepancy between the Python 3.8 library it is downloading to and the Python 3.9.5 I am using in Spyder, and that is the reason it doesn't show up. Does anyone know how to access the Python 3.8 downloads or generally have a way to access the script? I've also tried with a script updated for the recent Python iterations (https://github.com/jnothman/UpSetPlot) that does a similar function, but I'm getting the same error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Inside spyder try using `import pip` then run `!pip install py-upset` which should add it to your 3.9.5 environment.

Comment: 'Import pip' triggers the same ModuleNotFoundError, but when I do run the second line of code you sent it, it ultimately gives me this: 'Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010b7e1600 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>'.